# Двойное отрицание в jquery

Tags: jquery

В jquery есть двойное отрицание? А то такие условия нагромождают код.

```
if (index_i == 0) {
    index_i = 1;
} else {
    index_i = 0;
}
```

Хочется:

```
index_i = !!index_i;
```

Через тернарные тоже не хочу.

Comment: вы хотите в булевом типе просто поменять значение?

Comment: Именно. Спасибо.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

для описанного выше случая можно использовать

```
index_i ^= 1
```

вообще если надо менять между `0` и целым числом `n`

```
index_i ^= n
```